# Create backup in USB flash disk through virtual terminal

Tags: ubuntu, backup, tty

I am new to Ubuntu 13.10. Due to some error a black screen displays once I logon. I want to backup the important documents in a USB flash disk. So I logged into the Virtual terminal so that I can copy those files.

I am not going to boot through the USB disk. i just need to copy some files from my local directory into my USB disk. How do I do that.

Please help me out.
It's very important guys. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

It will show all your hard drives including the USB stick. (/dev/something)

If it is not already mounted you can mount it to /media/{whatever you want}

You may want to check if it is already, automatically mounted (which should be the case for Ubuntu) giving

```
sudo mount
```

Ok i see you are having a hard time there, so I ll give u an example. I currently have no USB stick with me, but I have an external hard drive. I m going to show you how can I recognize where it is mounted:

```
sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000e0f5d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758   625141759   312320001    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760   625141759   312320000   83  Linux

Disk /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt: 319.8 GB, 319813582848 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38881 cylinders, total 624635904 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/mint--vg-root: 315.6 GB, 315629764608 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38373 cylinders, total 616464384 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/mint--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/mint--vg-swap_1: 4164 MB, 4164943872 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 506 cylinders, total 8134656 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/mint--vg-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/sdb: 320.0 GB, 320044269568 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38909 cylinders, total 625086464 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0002e085

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   625086463   312542208    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

You can see that I have 2 physical drives (sda and sdb). /dev/sda is partitioned as you can see and one of the partitions is bootable. This indicates that it is the hard drive that Linux uses as the filesystem. The second drive /dev/sdb (320 GB) seems to be my external hard drive. I can verify it from its size (320 GB) and from the filesystem (HPFS/NTFS/exFAT) - your USB stick is likely having a file system like that.

Then I ll check if my hard drive is automatically mounted:

```
sudo mount
/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
//share/ee_groups_hst/PaCo_Ath on /mnt/share type cifs (rw)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=milonaki)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/mike/WD External type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```

You can see that /dev/sdb1 is mounted at /media/mike/WD External. If the output of this command did not provide a line containing /dev/sdb then I should mount my external hard drive manually.

Comment: Great but I am still stuck at the nameofusb. I did this: the sudo fdisk - l. It showed /dev/sdb1 next to my USB disk. So do I need to write

Comment: Provide the output  of sudo fdisk -l please

Comment: You are not booting from the USB stick right? You just want to copy files from your hard drive to the usb stick as I get it. If that's it you do not need to mount your /path/to/documents. A cp /path/to/documents /path/where/usb/is/mounted will do the job.

Comment: how do i know where the usb is mounted?

Comment: I cannot understand the output of fdisk -l like this. Can you give : sudo mount , then sudo fdisk -l and paste the output formatted, in your original question? (edit your original question and add the output of these 2 commands)

Comment: i am not able to access the terminal from the ubuntu desktop. i used Ctrl+Alt+F1 to log into the virtual terminal.
that's why I am not able to provide the formatted output.

Comment: Yeap I got that. You are still able to execute these commands from this terminal. Grap the output somehow and paste it here. The whole output pls :)

Comment: here's the link to the image output.
<a href="http://tinypic.com?ref=15s4ynb" target="_blank"><img src="http://i62.tinypic.com/15s4ynb.jpg" border="0" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic"></a>

hope the image's clean.

Comment: Ok so your USB is /dev/sdb (I assume it is 8 GB right). Now run sudo mount, and look for a line containing /dev/sdb1

Comment: As you said, the usb disk is 8gb in size.
I did as you instructed, but the pen-drive isn't mounted by default. I have formatted the usb disk as well (on a Windows laptop) but still to no use.
I think I need to mount it manually.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, u were a lifesaver !! I am a newbie to Ubuntu and hanging to Ubuntu from Windows was a bit troublesome.
I manually mounted the pen drive. (phew !!, however there were some errors). The only task now is how do I copy all my data into the pen drive so that I can use 'ls' to view all the copied data.

Comment: Successfully copied all the files, created the backup nicely, although it required quite a bit of research, all thanks to you and StackOverflow.